# Is there a smtp client included in Databricks platform to be able to send emails?

Tags: python, smtp, databricks

How can you send an email from a Databricks platform?
I would like to send an email from a notebook in Databricks with Python. I'm wondering if there's already an SMTP client already configured that I can use. I tried to do it, but didn't succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "no". There's no smtp client included in Databricks.

But you can define yours outside and use it through the Databricks platform.